# Import 150 text files to Access as Tables using SQL

Tags: vba, excel, csv, import

I have 150 text files in csv format using pipe | as a seperator.  the files are in different folders on a network.  The filenames are date specific and have a suffix which holds the date. I have created a table which has 3 fields: File Location; File Name excluding suffix; suffix (in format yymmdd).

I want to create an SQL script which will import each of the 150 files named in the table that I have created into 150 seperate Access 2007 tables named as the File Name excluding Suffix. I tried to do this using VBA but the filenames contain full stops and VBA didn't like this.

Each of the files has a different column structure but the first row is always headers.  I can only use Features native to Access 2007 as the organisation I work for does not allow third party addons or applications.  I don't have SQL server available to me.

I am a complete novice when it comes to Access and am struggling to achieve anything approaching this.  Can you help?

Comment: I struggled to achieve what I wanted in Access and so went over to Excel instead.  The code below creates each of the text files as a sheet within a single Excel workbook with the Master table holding the filename / path etc as a "Master" Sheet within the workbook.  It deletes all of the sheets other than "Master" before recreating them and if a file is not found it will leave a blank sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled to achieve what I wanted in Access and so went over to Excel instead. The code below creates each of the text files as a sheet within a single Excel workbook with the Master table holding the filename / path etc as a "Master" Sheet within the workbook. It deletes all of the sheets other than "Master" before recreating them and if a file is not found it will leave a blank sheet.

```
Sub ImportFiles()

'This script looks at a Master list of files for import and imports each to their own tab
'The files are pipe (|) delimited and can be in any addressable location
'If any files are not found, the import of that file is skipped, leaving a blank worksheet

'Close the Report File before starting the import
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Windows("Report.xlsx").Activate
    Windows("Report.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Start by looking at the sheet which contains the Master list of files
    Sheets("Master").Activate

'declare three arrays of unknown length
    Dim FileName() As String
    Dim FilePath() As String
    Dim FullName() As String

'initially there are no files
    Dim NumberFiles As Integer
    NumberFiles = 0

'loop over all of the file cells
'The master file needs to be structured FileName, FilePath and FullName in that order
'Change C2 to the cell containing the first FileName in the Master List
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim TopCell As Range
    Dim FileRange As Range

    Set TopCell = Range("C2")
    Set FileRange = Range(TopCell, TopCell.End(xlDown))
    For Each FileCell In FileRange

'we've found another file!
    NumberFiles = NumberFiles + 1

'for each file found, extend all arrays
    ReDim Preserve FileName(NumberFiles - 1)
    ReDim Preserve FilePath(NumberFiles - 1)
    ReDim Preserve FullName(NumberFiles - 1)

'now store the filename, path and fullname of the new file
    FileName(NumberFiles - 1) = FileCell.Value
    FilePath(NumberFiles - 1) = FileCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    FullName(NumberFiles - 1) = FileCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

Next FileCell

'delete any existing sheets except Master and create new blank sheets
For Each Sheet In Application.Worksheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Sheet.Name <> "Master" Then
    Sheet.Delete
    End If
    Next Sheet
    Sheets("Master").Activate
    For i = 1 To (NumberFiles)
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet" & i
    Next i
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'Start the process of import

'create a workbook object for the workbook where the current macro is running
    Dim ws As Worksheet

'import each file into its own sheet
    For i = 0 To (NumberFiles - 1)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & i + 1) 'the current sheet

'Ignore any missing files and carry on processing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next

'This imports the delimited files
    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FullName(i),     Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "a" & i
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With

'Rename tabs to name on master list
    ws.Name = "" & FileName(i)

    Next i

'Reopen the Report File
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Report.xlsx"

End Sub
```